# In Coq, why use Atom and how to construct it?

Tags: llvm, coq

I'm currently working with vellvm, developing a transformation on it. I'm a coq newbie.

This is the atom implementation: 
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~plclub/popl08-tutorial/code/coqdoc/Atom.html

In vellvm, atoms are used as ids and labels, for example.

I would like to insert a block of code in one llvm transformation, and for that I would have to give a label of type "atom". How can I construct a Atom label?

Putting my question a bit more general:
1) Why someone would want to use Atom?
2) How can I construct one?
3) If I construct this way, will I have trouble taking in consideration that the atoms might be used differently in the code?

Thanks!

Edit: Code for id and labels

```
Definition id := atom. (*r identities *) 
Definition l := atom. (*r labels *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the file you pointed (by Chargueraud and Aydemir), you understand that the atom type is used to represent any type that you could use to give names to things.

The function atom_fresh_for_list should be used to create a new atom.  The type of this function indicates that it returns not only an arbitrary atom, but also some proof that the atom you get is not present in the list you gave as argument.  This is how you create a new one: you put all the old ones in a list, and you call the function atom_fresh_for_list with it as argument.  As a result you obtain a value of type {x : atom | ...}.  This is not exactly an atom: it is an atom with more information.  You can get hold of the atom by writing:

let (v, h) := atom_fresh_for_list ... in ...

and then, in the second "...", the variable v contains the atom and you can use it.  If you need to prove that this atom is a new one, then you can use the other variable h for that.

Yves

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please give me a full example of how construct the first atom? For example, fill the following definition: Definition give_me_any_atom : atom :=

Answer (score 2):

Yves was able to answer it partially, just don't have an example of how to construct a atom. You need to use projT1. Following are the code for this:

```
Definition an_atom : atom := (projT1 (atom_fresh_for_list nil)).
```

Where nil is any list.